# Sharepoint password email redirectory

Tags: 2013, email, redirect, sharepoint-email

My organisation works in a direct sync environment so all our Microsoft products are linked via one account. Whenever a user clicks "forgot password" an email will be sent to the helpdesk and they will help users to restore their password. Only with our SharePoint whenever users click forgot password an email is sent to all the Admins. Is there a way to change this so only the helpdesk will receive this mail? I don't know if this change can be made in sharepoint or on server level.

Comment: Please provide more information for where a user is clicking "forgot password" and a screenshot for context.

Comment: Hi Eric, to answer your question. The user is clicking "forgot pasword" at the office 365 "sign in to your account" screen for webaccess. Our sharepoint admins then receive an email which says "request to change password". We would like that email to be redirected to the helpdesk. Of what would you like to see a screenshot off?